# How can I use Elixir + Vueify?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vueify

How can I use Elixir + Vueify like the Vue-Hackernews sample?

They use some command like this at the **package.json**

```
....
"scripts": {
    "dev": "watchify -v -t vueify -e src/main.js -o build/build.js",
    "build": "./node_modules/watchify/node_modules/.bin/browserify -t vueify src/main.js | uglifyjs -c -m > build/build.js"
}
...
```

But I do not know how to use it with Laravel Elixir

[Sample](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews/tree/browserify)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: I've tried, but I do not know how to use laravel elixir together with vueify ... for example git, he shows using browserify, and I was wondering how I use with the elixir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Install `sudo npm install laravel-elixir-browserify vue vueify --save`
2. In your `gulpfile.js` add the following:

   ```
   var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

   var vueify = require('laravel-elixir-browserify').init("vueify");

   elixir(function(mix) {
       // resources/assets/js/main.js
       mix.vueify('main.js', {insertGlobals: true, transform: "vueify", output: "public/js"});
   });
   ```
3. Be Happy =D

**Laravel Elixir Browserify Extension Doc
[Click Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-elixir-browserify)**

Comment: This worked me and I commented on an issue trying to bring vueify into existence.